# Fast conversion from gray level image to QImage

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-processing

In an application I handle images where each pixel is either an unsigned or a float with each value is a pixel with the given level of grey. I have the source available so I can access the data of the images freely.

I need to display/save and load these pictures using the qt framework. Currently the only way of handling the conversion is to get and set each pixel which is proving to be a bit slow.

Are there any other way one could convert these images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using QImage::setPixel you should access to the image buffer directly.

After you create the image with the desidered format, width and height, you can use QImage::bits() to access the memory buffer, or also QImage::scanLine() to retrieve a pointer to the beginning of each line in the image and set the pixels directly in memory: this is much faster than calling setPixel() for each pixel.

Comment: Upvoted. If you're going for programming safety, I'd have Qt allocate the memory instead of giving a data pointer to the QImage ctor like Johannes offers. (This is a valid optimization technique, but there's a saying about premature optimization which you might know). So let Qt allocate memory for a QImage with the right size and byte format, then memcpy() your data into the memory area pointed at by QImage::bits().

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Good point about copying, but I assumed that the OP needed the conversion to QImage only temporary for display/load/save. But still, definitely better memcopy than pixelwise set/get.

Comment: @JohannesS. Copying the data of a gray-scale image is not the most expensive operation in the process probably. For example, consider that QImage most likely needs to be converted to ARGB32_Premultiplied anyway when it's rendered on screen. Thus I'd not worry about this in the very first instant and go with the safer method.

Comment: @JohannesS. memcpy cannot be used if the original values are float: a loop has to read them and write into the image them as integers. Also, the destination buffer has the scanlines aligned on a 32 bit boundary, while the source may have another alignment. Therefore the easiest way is to use QImage::scanLine() and copy the source values into each scan line.

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli Can you elaborate, why row-wise memcopy (eg. using QImage::scanLine()) does not work for `float` values?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Well, I don't see, why I myself should go through the hassle of converting the grayscale image to ARGB32_Premultiplied until it is shown that this is significantly faster. I _do_ believe however (profile, if you like) that block-wise copy (row-wise or not, depends on your alignment etc) is signficantly faster than the get/setPixel the OP mentioned in his original post.

Comment: @JohannesS. QImage doesn't have any format that accepts floats as pixel values

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry about the noise. Totally missed this (since we used to display our images with native OpenGL on a QGLWidget). Thank you

Comment: This is perfect for me. It solves the alignment problem, and should be quicker than the current solution.

Answer (score 2):

`QImage` has a constructor that takes a pointer to an existing buffer/image:

```
    QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
```

It does not take ownership of the buffer nor does it copy the contents, so you are responsible that the buffer is valid throughout the lifetime of the `QImage`.

*Note:* `QImage` requires 32-bit aligned image rows, so you might need to copy the image rowwise into a new buffer with appropriate padding. You have only unsigned or float pixels, so it doesn't apply for you (already 32bit values), but remember it, should you have different pixel types in the future.

Comment: This was a solution I was looking at myself, but I was hesitant because of the 32 bit alignment issues, and the complexity it would add to code that now is very simple. But still it is a solution.